# Remove all spaces before a character in a line

Tags: c++

I have this peculiar requirement where I need to remove all space characters before a specific character which is a pipe'|'.
I have written a test code for it which is actually printing the right output but additionally gifting me a core file :(

My code is below:

```
int main()
{

    string line="1  2  |3 4| hbvhwf     wjff wenf|hjbcwbfw     ejwef   efwk    dfkwe|jsv                       |";
    cout <<line<<endl;
    string::iterator ite =(line.begin());

    int counter=0;
    int index=0;
    int start=0;
    while(ite != (line.end()))
    {
        if(*ite == '|' && counter > 0)
        {
            line.erase(start,counter);
            counter=0;
            cout<<line<<endl;
        }
        if(ite!=line.end())
        {
            if(isalnum(*ite))
            {
                counter=0;
            }
            if(*ite==' ')
            {
                if(!counter)
                {
                    start=index;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            ite++;
            index++;        
        }
    }

    cout<<line<<endl;
}
```

I am just going nuts in finding the root cause of the core dump.
Could anybody please help?
expected output is:

```
1  2|3 4| hbvhwf     wjff wenf|hjbcwbfw     ejwef   efwk    dfkwe|jsv|
```

Comment: Once you call erase on your line you need to reset the iterator.

Comment: It should be done automatically I think. I donot have to do it As far as my understanding is concerned.

Comment: @user1939168 [`std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) returns an iterator. You should assign it to `ite` in your code.

Comment: @user1939168 It is not done automatically. You do "have to do it". Any operation that alters the string can invalidate existing iterators into it.

Comment: @rubenvb the sequence version of erase() OP is using doesn't return an iterator, it return *this. The range version does.

Comment: @jfly I blame Friday. Ignore me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Krzysztof's answer says, the reason of the core dump is the `erase()` invalidated the iterators. To solve this, you need to reset the iterator correctly, use the [range version](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) of `erase()`, your will get an iterator referring to the character that now occupies the position of the first character erased, and assign it to ite. Change the first if statement to the code below, it should work fine.

```
    if(*ite == '|' && counter > 0)
    {
        ite = line.erase(ite - counter, ite);

        counter=0;
        cout<<line<<endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `erase()` on a string invalidates all iterators into the string, including `ite`.

Specifically, when `line.erase(start,counter);` executes, `ite` is invalidated - it is no longer guaranteed to refer to a valid position in the string. If it's not equal to `line.end()`, it can be dereferenced in the condition `isalnum(*ite)`. Because `ite` is invalidated at that point, it can refer to memory which is already freed (e.g. if the string was reallocated after being erased). Therefore this line causes a segfault.

Here is a simpler version of your code, which does not have the problem.

```
std::string line = ...;
unsigned space_run = 0;

for (unsigned i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i) {
    if (line[i] == ' ') {
        ++space_run;
    } else if (line[i] == '|') {
        line.erase(i - space_run, space_run);
        i -= space_run;
        space_run = 0;
    } else {
        space_run = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1939168 - The bug in your code is that you are using invalidated iterators. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: I added an explanation of what was wrong with your original code.

Comment: Thanks. This is working . But would like to select the answer which pointed out my mistake clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line="1  2  |3 4| hbvhwf     wjff wenf|hjbcwbfw     ejwef   efwk    dfkwe|jsv                       |";
    cout <<line<<endl;

    string res;
    size_t length =  line.size();
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0 ; --i)
    {
        if (line[i] == '|')
        {
            res.push_back(line[i]);
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (flag && line[i] == ' ')
        {

        }
        else
        {
            res.push_back(line[i]);
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    copy(res.rbegin(), res.rend(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, ""));
    cout<<endl;
}
```

The ouput is:

```
1  2  |3 4| hbvhwf     wjff wenf|hjbcwbfw     ejwef   efwk    dfkwe|jsv                       |
1  2|3 4| hbvhwf     wjff wenf|hjbcwbfw     ejwef   efwk    dfkwe|jsv|
```